# Some months are not recognised by lubridate::parse_date_time() in R

Tags: r, date, date-parsing, data-cleaning

Month is not recognied by the function , for example

```
x <- c("20-DEC-2006","01-JUL-2007","1991")
lubridate::parse_date_time(x, c("dbY", "ymd HM","Y")) 
output :[1] NA               "2007-07-01 UTC" "1991-01-01 UTC"
```

december is not recognised , this is same with march,may and october. Could someone please explain me the reason behind it. Thanks a lot

Comment: not able to reproduce it. what is the package version that you are using?

Comment: Also, what locale do you have, and is 'Dec' the usual shortcut in that locale (as opposed to, say, 'Dez')?

Comment: @Tushar - version is lubridate_1.6.0 dplyr_0.7.1

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel locale is Germany

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks a lot for the tip .... :) .. the issue was with the locale. Once i changed that to english , it worked!!!